# ElasticSearch normalizer performance impact

Tags: elasticsearch

We would like to use normalizers to be able to do case insensitive queries to elastic.

```
"analysis": {
     "normalizer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "filter": [
              "lowercase"
           ]
        }
     }
  }
```

Which is the performance in the queries operations using normalizers in our Keyword properties?

Reading documentation explains during index building it applies the normalizers to the set properties (I guess most of the work is doing during index building) but documentation says some more operations are done when data is queried.

The operations when data is queried is just to normalize the query text, or is doing something more? Which is the performance impact using normalizers?

Thanks

Comment: It will Run it through the whole analyzer pipeline https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-text-analysis-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer logic will be applied on the field of the data you are indexing on index time once. Moreover every time you do a query the analyzer logic will be applied on your query when search against the field that uses that particular analyzer. 
Summarising, an analyzer will be applied once on index time (on your save input) and always on query time (on your search input).